# How to set Interval time for the GPS location Confirmation popup in iOS using Xamarin forms

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, gps, location

I'm new in Xamarin forms, I'm using GPS location in my application and i did set for the 
    access GPS location code in info.plist file for iOS. 
    Mentioned in the below code I did use.
       **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
       **You are about to use location!**
       **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**
       This will be called if location is used behind the scenes
    when I open the app then shows the confirmation popup but it was showed 2-3 seconds in time duration I'm not able to allow GPS  confirmation so in this case, my application has crashed.how to set interval time in confirmation popup Please suggest me what I do for this.

Answer (score 0):

After iOS 11.0 , we would better add a new description `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` in info.plist . The  `interval time` in iOS is defined by system which could not customize . But we could request the permission in advance .

For permissions in Xamarin.Forms , you could use the plugin **[Plugin.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/5.0.0-beta)**

#### Usage

```
try
{
    PermissionStatus status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
       if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
       {
          await DisplayAlert("Need location", "app need that location", "OK");
       }

       Dictionary<Permission,PermissionStatus> result = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        //Query permission
    }

    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
      //location denied
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Something went wrong
}
```

You can invoke the above code in MainPage of the app .

Comment: Thanks for gave replay,

Not working for me, getting error "location services are not enabled on device"

Comment: Which device did you test ? You could share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: In Android version 9 and  iOS version 12.4.3.
for iOS i have set key in info.plist file  for the permission 
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>You are about to use location!</string>
 <!--<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This will be called if location is used behind the scenes</string>-->

Comment: And I have set the location code in App.xaml.cs file
      var lTS = new TaskCompletionSource<Location>();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                if (location == null)
                    location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();
                if (location!=null)
                    lTS.SetResult(location);
            });

Comment: You could share a sample because I could not reproduce the issue